# Excessive Page Indexing in Google Search Console for a Small Site

Tags: google-search-console

I'm a beginner with Google Search Console and I've encountered a serious problem: GSC is showing around 6 million discovered pages for my website, while there are only about 100 pages actually on the site.

My website URL: https://hlb.tj/

The issue began with a large number of links on my site redirecting to an unrelated third-party website. This redirection has since ceased, but the indexing issue persists.

Steps I've already taken:

Checked the robots.txt file.
Used the "Remove URLs" feature in GSC.
Scanned the site with the free version of the Wordfence plugin for WordPress, found, and removed a few viruses.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is not a programming question and it is off-topic on Stack Overflow. Non-programming questions about your website should be asked on [webmasters.se]. However, as it is currently worded, this question would be closed as off-topic on Webmasters because it is specific to your site. When you delete it here and ask it there, please include enough details that it isn't just "what is wrong with my site?" Ideally, you wouldn't need to link to your site at all.